# Reading multiple CSV files and joining them horizontally

Tags: python, regex, linux, pandas, csv

I have a couple of files in csv format like `100-age.csv 100-rel.csv 100-gender.csv 101-age.csv ... 101-gender.csv ... 482-rel.csv 482-gender.csv` etc. I have to make new file for every index i.e. `100-combo.csv` which which will join `100-age.csv 100-rel.csv` and `100-gender.csv` **horizontally**. I could do this for one file using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

age = pd.read_csv('100-age.csv', header=None)
gender = pd.read_csv('100-gender.csv', header=None)
rel = pd.read_csv('100-rel.csv', header=None)

combined = pd.concat([age, gender, rel], axis=1)

combined.to_csv('100-combo.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

Using linux, there are methods like `cat` which only add vertically, i.e. stacking on top of each other and `paste` command which disturbs the formatting that I have in these files.

```
    def merged_data(i):   

        age = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'.pdf-age.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
        gender = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'.pdf-gender.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
        rel = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'.pdf-rel.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
        combined = pd.concat([age, gender, rel], axis=1)
        combined['block'] = str(i)
        combined.to_csv(path+str(i)+'-combo.csv', header=None, index=None)

for num in range(1,483):

    merged_data(num)
```

I am getting this error

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

But, I know that all my data files have some or other values

Comment: I believe that the code in pandas can be used but how do I do this for multiple files, how can that loop be written?

Comment: you don't know how to concatenate strings?

Comment: I know that, where do I use that in this case, though?

Comment: `"100-age.csv"` is just `str(100) + "-age.csv"` and i'm sure you can find a `range` that suits better your needs

Comment: Hi @bobrobbob I also need to make a column while concatenating which will have the index number i in all the rows, is the code for the same right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this and got what I wanted. I used

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.common import EmptyDataError

    def merged_data(i):   
        try:
            age = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'.pdf-age.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False, delim_whitespace=True)
        except EmptyDataError:
            age = pd.DataFrame()
        try:  
            gender = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'.pdf-gender.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False, delim_whitespace=True)
        except EmptyDataError:
            gender = pd.DataFrame()
        try:
            rel = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'.pdf-rel.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False, delim_whitespace=True)
        except EmptyDataError:
            rel = pd.DataFrame()
            combined = pd.concat([age, gender, rel], axis=1)
            combined['block'] = str(i)
            combined.to_csv(path+str(i)+'-combo.csv', header=None, index=None)

for num in range(1,483):

    merged_data(num)
```