# Pandas not reading or writing to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Written below is the question I asked yesterday.

[Reading multiple CSV files and joining them horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209153/reading-multiple-csv-files-and-joining-them-horizontally)

The code I wrote worked perfectly fine yesterday and I was able to get the combined csv files, but when I want to do it to other folder, by changing path name and file name, the variables and dataframes are not gettings initialised. Here is the code I have written

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.common import EmptyDataError

path = '~/Documents/EditedElectoral/Torpa_Full_Data/'

def merged_data(i):   
    try:
        age = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'_trimmed.pdf-age.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False, delim_whitespace=True)
    except EmptyDataError:
        age = pd.DataFrame()
    try:  
        gender = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'_trimmed.pdf-gender.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False, delim_whitespace=True)
    except EmptyDataError:
        gender = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        rel = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+'_trimmed.pdf-rel.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False, delim_whitespace=True)
    except EmptyDataError:
        rel = pd.DataFrame()

    combined = pd.concat([age, gender, rel], axis=1)
    combined['block'] = str(i)
    combined.to_csv(path+str(i)+'-combined.csv', header=None, index=None)

for num in range(1,242):

    merged_data(num)
```

The first error was that csv was not getting exported. When I tried running `combined.info()` and `age.info()` I got `NameError: name 'combined' is not defined`

The file is running properly without any errors, but I am not getting the output. Does it mean that I am committing a logical error? What mistake am I doing in this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the extension, I just tried reading a csv file with your extension and it fails, you need to have just one dot and end with csv.

No idea how it worked before, but it's not the right way

Comment: Hi, Carlos, but the extension was the same in other folders also and it worked perfectly fine last time.

Comment: Try just using the .csv file. If it works at least you know the cause. If it doesn't I will try to think of something else